# Why uploadArchives uploads artifacts from other configurations?

Tags: upload, gradle, artifact

I'm puzzled why Gradle's `uploadArchive` is uploading artifacts from other configurations. My understanding is that when you declare a configuration it will get an upload task for you and when called it will upload the artifacts assigned to its configuration.

That's not the behavior I'm seeing:

```
apply plugin: 'base'

configurations {
  foo
}

task fooIt(type: Zip) {
  from 'blah.txt'
  baseName 'foo'
}

task barIt(type: Zip) {
  from 'blah.txt'
  baseName 'bar'
}

artifacts {
  foo fooIt
}

repositories {
  flatDir {
    name 'local'
    dirs 'repo'
  }
}

uploadArchives {
  repositories {
    add project.repositories.local
  }
}

uploadFoo {
  repositories {
    add project.repositories.local
  }
}
```

In this example there are no artifacts assigned to the `archives` configuration but when I call `gradle uploadArchives` it will upload `foo`'s artifacts.

```
$ gradle -i uploadArchives
All projects evaluated.
Selected primary task 'uploadArchives' from project :
Tasks to be executed: [task ':fooIt', task ':uploadArchives']
:fooIt (Thread[Daemon Thread 17,5,main]) started.
:fooIt
Skipping task ':fooIt' as it is up-to-date (took 0.008 secs).
:fooIt UP-TO-DATE
:fooIt (Thread[Daemon Thread 17,5,main]) completed. Took 0.017 secs.
:uploadArchives (Thread[Daemon Thread 17,5,main]) started.
:uploadArchives
Executing task ':uploadArchives' (up-to-date check took 0.0 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
Publishing configuration: configuration ':archives'
Publishing to Repository 'local'
Published :gradle:unspecified:foo.zip to file:/private/tmp/gradle/repo/foo-unspecified.zip
Published :gradle:unspecified:ivy.xml to file:/private/tmp/gradle/repo/ivy-unspecified.xml
:uploadArchives (Thread[Daemon Thread 17,5,main]) completed. Took 0.017 secs.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Two questions out of this:

1. Why is `fooIt` getting executed?
2. Why is `uploadArchives` uploading `foo`'s artifacts?

Thanks

```
$ gradle --version
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2014-09-08 10:40:39 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     e6cf70745ac11fa943e19294d19a2c527a669a53

Groovy:       2.3.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.7.0_45 (Oracle Corporation 24.45-b08)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.10.2 x86_64
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `archives` configuration contains all artifacts from all configurations. I believe the confusion comes from the fact that you can also add artifacts directly to the `archives` configuration if you want. That being the case, the `uploadArchives` task will always upload all the declared artifacts. If you want to upload a subset of your artifacts then you should call the `upload<<ConfigurationName>>` task.